# How to SQL query group concate into laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my query in SQL. i need to convert into Laravel query. becuase this query is not effected on Laravel blade. so I need to convert in Laravel query. can anyone know how to do this ?

### Laravel Controller

```
   class BookingDetailsController extends Controller
   {
       public function booking_list()
       {
           $role = Auth::user()->role;

           $data['page_title'] = "Booking Detail";
           $data['page_description'] = "Welcome to Admin Dashboard"; 
            $booking_detail = DB::select('SELECT bd.id as book_id, bd.recept_no, bd.advance_payment,bd.total_balance,
                               bd.is_booked, cc.name,  GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.rate SEPARATOR \'|\'), 
                               GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.pickup_point SEPARATOR \'|\'),  
                               GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.drop_point SEPARATOR \'|\'),  
                               GROUP_CONCAT(cn.car_number SEPARATOR \'|\') FROM booking_details bd
                               left join driver_car_booking_details dcb on bd.id = dcb.booking_id
                               left join car_nos cn on dcb.vehicle_id = cn.id
                               inner join customers cc on bd.customer_id = cc.id
                               group by bd.id
                               order by bd.id' ); 

           if($role == 'admin'){
               dd($booking_detail);
               return view('admin.booking_list')->with($data)
               ->with('booking_detail', $booking_detail);
           }
           if($role == 'oil_filling'){
               return view('oil_filling.booking_list')->with($data)
               ->with('booking_detail', $booking_detail);
           }else{
               return view('admin.booking_list')->with($data)
               ->with('booking_detail', $booking_detail);
           }

       }
}
```

the raw query:

```
    SELECT bd.id as book_id, bd.recept_no, bd.advance_payment,bd.total_balance,
            bd.is_booked, cc.name,  GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.rate SEPARATOR '|'), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.pickup_point SEPARATOR '|'),  
    GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.drop_point SEPARATOR '|'),  
    GROUP_CONCAT(cn.car_number SEPARATOR '|') FROM booking_details bd
            left join driver_car_booking_details dcb on bd.id = dcb.booking_id
            left join car_nos cn on dcb.vehicle_id = cn.id
            inner join customers cc on bd.customer_id = cc.id
            group by bd.id
            order by bd.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw query builder methods can be used to execute queries without using the ORM.

The following snippet would execute the above query:

```
      $bookings = DB::select('SELECT bd.id as book_id, bd.recept_no, bd.advance_payment,bd.total_balance,
        bd.is_booked, cc.name,  GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.rate SEPARATOR \'|\'), 
GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.pickup_point SEPARATOR \'|\'),  
GROUP_CONCAT(dcb.drop_point SEPARATOR \'|\'),  
GROUP_CONCAT(cn.car_number SEPARATOR \'|\') FROM booking_details bd
        left join driver_car_booking_details dcb on bd.id = dcb.booking_id
        left join car_nos cn on dcb.vehicle_id = cn.id
        inner join customers cc on bd.customer_id = cc.id
        group by bd.id
        order by bd.id');
```

Comment: i used your query but no result shown. blank page show.

Comment: A blank page often indicates an 500 error, could you check the error logs? @zeeshan

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
@MaartenDev

Comment: That is a browser error, could you add your laravel controller code to your question? @zeeshan

Comment: Dev check question now

Comment: Does it show an error or just a blank page? @zeeshan

Comment: just show blank page on title show whoops!there was error. i dont why they show this type of error

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the error page? @zeeshan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198778/discussion-between-maartendev-and-zeeshan).